# Chrome IFrame blocking out Flash (Flash in CKEditor popup above the CKEditor IFrame)

Tags: flash, google-chrome, ckeditor

An image says a thousand words:
http://i35.tinypic.com/hu3a1e.png

A flash object in a CKEditor dialog is being blocked by the IFrame element. This only happens on Chrome. I have tried changing the z-index, that didn't work at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got such a problem. My iframe and flash elements was right in body element, the solution is to wrap them with extra div.

Comment: I am seeing this behaviour even though neither iframe nor flash are at the root of the body element; they are already wrapped in divs. Did you manage to understand the problem any better, by any chance?